# why source sending mail (gmail )in matlab don't work?

Tags: matlab, email, send

I want to send an email via Gmail in MATLAB R2015a. This is my code:

```
my_default_email_address = 'mygmail@gmail.com';
my_username = 'mygmail';
my_password = 'mypass';

setpref('Internet','E_mail',my_default_email_address);
setpref('Internet','SMTP_Server','smtp.gmail.com');
setpref('Internet','SMTP_Username',my_username);
setpref('Internet','SMTP_Password',my_password);

props = java.lang.System.getProperties;
props.setProperty('mail.smtp.auth','true');
props.setProperty('mail.smtp.socketFactory.class','javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory');
props.setProperty('mail.smtp.socketFactory.port','465');
sendmail('recipient@example.com' , 'subject of the email', 'text of the email');
```

but it doesn't work and it returns these errors:

> Error using send mail (line 171)
>   Authentication failed.
>
> Error in email (line 14)
>   sendmail('recipient@example.com' , 'subject of the email', 'text of the email');

I even opened and logged on to my Gmail in a browser, but it still throws this error. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your username should include the domain name as well. Set `my_username` to `mygmail@gmail.com` and try again.

Edit: Make sure access for less secure apps is turned on. Read more [here](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en).

Comment: Have you turned on this setting? https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en